# Как правильно писать: "Код неверен" или "Код не верен"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно писать: "Код неверен" или "Код не верен"?

Answer (score 3):

Я выбираю первую форму (неверен), но оба варианта имеют право на жизнь.

Слитное написание указывает на ошибочность кода, раздельное - отказывает ему в правильности.

Вот как этот момент разъясняет [Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_04):

> Эта задача нетрудная (утверждается «легкость») – это задача не трудная
> (отрицается «трудность»).

А краткая форма прилагательного сохраняет написание полной.

Answer (score 3):

При отсутствии противопоставления (напр. в диалоге), когда возможно формальное отрицание частицей *не* приписываемого коду (напр. собеседником) качества "верности":

> Код не "верен", а абсолютно точен!

нужно исходить из слитного написания прилагательного (здесь - краткого) с отрицательной приставкой:

> Код неверен. (= Это неверный код.)

Answer (score 1):

**Код неверен.**

У кода только две возможности: он верен (верный код) или неверен (неверный код). (Код не может быть абсолютно верным,  или немного неверным, или еще каким).

Никаких дополнительных значений раздельная форма не дает,  поэтому нет смысла  использовать отрицание.

Comment: Это можно утверждать лишь в простейших случаях (пин-код карты и т. п.). Но код - широкое понятие. Даже если оставить в стороне "программные коды" (запись программ на машинном языке), которые подвергаются отладке в процессе приближения к нужной степени "верности", то разной степенью "верности" могут обладать и коды в виде просто числовых последовательностей - _корректирующие коды_ с избыточными символами, которые в зависимости от количества имеющихся в них ошибок (в такие коды заложена возможность исправления некоторого их количества) выполняют свою функцию с той или иной степенью вероятности.

Comment: Такой код может быть передан (в услових помех) абсолютно верно (все символы точно совпадают), либо относительно верно (имеющиеся ошибки можно частично или полностью исправить). Поэтому в некоторых контекстах рассуждения о степени верности возможны.

Comment: Всё это возможно, но отражается ли в языке такое расширенное понимание кода?  Что нам дает запись "код не верен" по сравнению с записью "код неверен", они чем-то отличаются по смыслу?  Кстати, в Интернете пользователи эти две формы никак не различают и пишут как кому нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Код неверен, т.к можно заменить на неточный, неправильный

Comment: Одно слово с "не" заменили на два других: "Код не точный", "код не правильный". Вот если бы предложили замену в виде "код сложный" или "код запутанный" -- тогда да, было бы правильно.